# How to show/stream webcam with few seconds delay?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, delay

I want a webcam to record and a screen to show the "live"stream with a few seconds delay.

**Use case:** need to record a performance and display it almost live, with few seconds delay for a quick review. Performance takes a few seconds max, need to display it (review) right away without any manual clicking. There's lots of tries, manual clicking would make the process a lot longer.

**Possible sources:**

- main camera on an Android 6.0.1 phone (front one cloudy like a GB's landscape)
- main or front camera on an Android 6.0 tablet
- webcam on a laptop (Linux Ubuntu 17.04 or Windows 8.1) - no separate GPU

**Possible displays:**

- Android tablet, as above
- laptop, as above

**Other info:**

- no audio needed
- common WiFi network
- IP Webcam already installed on phone and tablet
- programming skills (I prefer Python)
- can setup a nginx server
- ...on the net too
- internet connection

**Essentials:**

- actually showing a readable stream with >=2s delay

**Nice-to-haves:**

- not using internet
- adjustable delay, if not: in range 3-6s
- good quality
- record on demand
- super duper feature: ability to record back (on click last x seconds are saved)

Generally using laptop's webcam and displaying stream on it's screen with a custom delay would be awesome.

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5149

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Open Broadcast Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/) If you have the payed version of this software you can use the `Studio Mode` which preview the stream before they go live. It can be installed on Windows, Mac and Linux and is open source.

You can fork it on github and change the code as needed (Skills required :))

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Miguel Grinberg has written an excellent video streaming tutorial in Python which sends JPEG frames successively. Check his blog post here:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask[1](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Each of these JPEG can be quickly reviewed and then broadcasted. [To take the required Delay in consideration]

As far as getting the input video feed is concerned, you can interface a webcam using OPENCV. OpenCV uses VideoCapture which returns raw images as bytes. These bytes needs to be encoded to JPEG and interfaced with Miguel's code.

```
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
    # Using OpenCV to capture from device
    self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
    self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
    success, image = self.video.read()
    # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
    # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
    # video stream.
    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    return jpeg.tobytes()
```

This approach will help you cater all the required features:

- No internet required
- Adjustable delay - Easily control the delay and the processing you want to perform on each frame
- Good Quality
- Record on Demand -  Store the captured frames as per need
- Have a record back feature, by just saving the previous 24*x frames (24fps stream)

Answer (score 1):

I tried in one of my project the tokbox which is fairly simple.

The tokbox is paid and it support python.
the link is [tokbox](https://tokbox.com/)

Also there are many available apis which are free
like [Apache Open Meeting](https://elearningindustry.com/top-6-open-source-web-conferencing-software-tools-elearning-professionals) .Python sample are available in github .

For more information and evaluation purpose of other api's you can go through this link
[Open source conferencing products comparison](https://elearningindustry.com/top-6-open-source-web-conferencing-software-tools-elearning-professionals)

Additional details are available at wiki

http://opensourceecology.org/wiki/Videoconferencing

With NGINX exactly [here](https://www.nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/) is the link.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this tool will help: [Kinovea](http://www.kinovea.org/), if you look in its [features](http://www.kinovea.org/documents/Kinovea.0.8.15.en.pdf)  under "Live Capture" there is an option for delaying a live stream.